# Custom Data Validation with possible Number or Word

Tags: validation, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Ok so here is what I have so far. The following works properly preventing non numbers and more than 2 occurrences of each number.

```
=AND(ISNUMBER(K2),COUNTIF(K$2:K$20,K2)<3)
```

Next I need to add in the option for the field to be 'BYE'. 
So each of the cells can contain a number that cannot occur more than twice or it can contain 'BYE'

Anyone have any advice on how to achieve this? Is there a way to say it can be like this or like that?

Comment: Wouldn't wrapping it in `OR` work? `=OR(K2="BYE",AND(...))`

Comment: Thanks the following worked great.

Comment: =OR(K2="BYE",AND(ISNUMBER(K2),COUNTIF(K$2:K$20,K2)<3))

Comment: I'm an iOS Developer so not familiar with using sheets. Feel free to submit it as an answer and I will mark it as best.

Comment: Have done. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `OR`.

`=OR(K2="BYE",AND(ISNUMBER(K2),COUNTIF(K$2:K$20,K2)<3))`